# Custom search in Quick2Cart Joomla

Tags: joomla

I need a custom search filter for Quick2Cart Joomla. Couldn't find anything online regarding this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you could not find any, you probably have to write your own search plugin for this. If you have programming experience it should not be especially difficult. You can start here:  [Creating a search plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin)